# Unable to improve speed of operation of ios app using grand central dispatch

Tags: ios, ios7, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, ios7.1

The time consuming task at hand is to query a database to get latitude and longitude values of some paths and trails. Now, I have several of these database operations to be performed for different types of trails and path. I am using the following to:

```
dispatch_async(myBackgroundQueue, ^(void) {

            // do some time consuming things here
            [self queryForHiking: ulLat ulLong:ulLon lrLat:lrLat lrLong:lrLon];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                // do some things here in the main queue
                // for example: update UI controls, etc.
                [self drawOnMap];
            });
        });
```

Like the above block of code, I have 5 blocks like this. The drawOnMap function draws the trails and path formed on the map. But it is taking a lot of time to render all the paths(from different queries) on the map. Especially, on a higher zoom level, where there is more data to be rendered, the app gets hanged and takes a lot of time to resume and display the data. How can I make it efficient?

EDIT: I think the query takes a lot of time here and I have 5 of such queries which are independent from one another. The following is one of my five query function:

```
 - (void)queryForHikingTrails:(NSString*)ulLat ulLong:(NSString*)ulLong lrLat:(NSString*)lrLat lrLong:(NSString*)lrLong
 {
     @try {
         [_db inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

             FMResultSet *trails = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT ID2,Latitude, Longitude FROM hikingtrails WHERE Latitude BETWEEN %@ and %@ AND Longitude BETWEEN %@ and %@", lrLat, ulLat, lrLong, ulLong];

             hikingTrails = [self buildTrails:trails];
         }];
     }
     @catch (NSException *e) {
         NSLog(@"Error Querying for Trails: %@ - %@", [e name], [e reason]);
     }
     @finally {
     }
 }
```

The following is the time taken when I run just this query(hiking):

Time taken by the query: 0.053462
Time taken by the redraw function (drawOnMap)=0.000008

When I run two queries(hiking+some other trails):

Time taken by the query: 2.681138
Time taken by the redraw function (drawOnMap)=0.000010

I don't have the privilege to change the database in any way. i.e., I cannot split the table or normalize it.

The database consist of around 18000 entries for hiking alone which the above function is trying to query.

Is there any way besides applying the database optimization to make the queries fast, at least run them in the background simultaneously (all 5)?

EDIT: I have further investigated and found that it is only one query that is taking a lot of time(11.7834) while others are not taking much time. How should I handle this particular query? Is there a way by which I can make this query run in the background without blocking the mapview. I don't know how that will be possible because each time this query is run the mapview is refreshed by the function drawOnMap. Please guide me.

Comment: Identify whether the time is due to the queries or the drawing, then update your question with more detail about the specific code that you want to optimize.

Comment: That's sort of wrong, @erikprice, you don't *think* something takes a lot of time. You measure it. Insert timing code (comparisons with ``NSDate`` may be fine) and first figure out what is the bottleneck. Measure how long does the DB loading take compared to UI drawing, then optimise the slowest one. Then repeat until satisfied. For SQL you have indices or table splitting, for drawing you have tiling.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamHankiewicz-I have updated the question with the time taken and found that the query is the bottleneck.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamHankiewicz I'm confused; did I say something about _thinking_ something takes a lot of time?

Comment: Sorry for the noise @erikprice, I incorrectly attributed this to you when I meant the first edit by KunalShrivastava. At least he's getting somewhere and now the question narrowed down to SQL optimisation, which should get a separate question with specifics on how to optimise the query and likely doesn't have anything to do with objective-c or gcd.

Comment: Ah gotcha. No problem.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamHankiewicz: Yes, it was SQL query optimization that I needed. Turns out that the join query was taking a lot of time. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the approach I suggest below works for you, but maybe it can be of some help. It uses an operation queue to execute your queries concurrently, and only when they are all finished does it call `-[self drawOnMap]`. However, in order for it to work correctly, each of your queries has to block the current thread. I inferred from your original GCD-based code that this was the case. But it also assumes that your query methods can execute concurrently in safety (e.g., that whatever you do with the query results can be done safely from multiple threads).

NSOperation dependencies give you an easy way to specify that work may be performed concurrently, and then do one final update when that work is complete:

```
self.queryQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

NSBlockOperation *queriesOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self queryForHiking:ulLat ulLong:ulLon lrLat:lrLat lrLong:lrLon];
}];
[queriesOperation addOperation:^{
    [self performSomeOtherQuery];
}];
[queriesOperation addOperation:^{
    [self performYetAnotherQuery];
}];
// do this for each of your queries

NSOperation *drawOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self drawOnMap];
}];
[drawOperation addDependency:queriesOperation];

[self.queryQueue addOperation:queriesOperation];
[NSOperationQueue.mainQueue addOperation:drawOperation];
```

Comment: Although, the the problem turned out to be an inefficient SQL join query. Still, I used your idea to make sure that the rendering of data is improved. It helped! So I am accepting your answer. Thanks.